# Cypress Frame management

Tags: javascript, frame, cypress

I'm trying to test my Add personal page on my website with cypress,there is a button on page I can get this like

`cy.get('#addBtnTd > .iframe-modal > img').click()`

then it opens a medium window, it got some input, dropdown areas and save button but cypress selector ground I can't get this inputs,
I added this to cypress.json

`{ "chromeWebSecurity": false }`
and also

`cy.get("iframe")` then on iframe window ->

`cy.get('#ddLevel0').select('A Bank ')` it says element is not visible

I want to be able to fill these input areas form frame with cypress.type and .select for drop-down list

Thank you.Any Help

Comment: Read this it has the iframe solution. https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/136